# Grails/GORM : org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in xyz (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I've a grails/jaxrs app that fails to persist a nested object graph automatically, and was wondering if there was something I could do with the datamodel to make it work.

The resource deserializes the object properly, then will save the parent object (Tauthor), but fail to save the children (Tooks) automatically.  The children have null ids, as well as null references to the parent.

I can manually create the child objects, but I am looking for a better way to manage this.

**Domain classes**

```
class Tauthor {

    String nameShort
    Integer age

    static hasMany = [tooks:Took]

}

class Took {

    String title;

    static belongsTo = [tauthor:Tauthor]
}
```

**Resource**

```
@Consumes([MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/json"])
@Produces([MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/json"])
@Path('/api/tauthor')
class TauthorResource {

    TauthorService tauthorService

    @POST
    Tauthor create(Tauthor dto) {
      Tauthor created = tauthorService.save(dto)
      if(!created.hasErrors()) {
        return created
      }
    }
}
```

**Desired, but broken service**

```
class TauthorService {

    Tauthor save(Tauthor dto) {
        dto.validate()

        if (dto.hasErrors()) {
            return dto
        }

        return dto.save()
    }
}
```

**Working service**

```
class TauthorService {

    Tauthor save(Tauthor dto) {
        dto.validate()

        if (dto.hasErrors()) {
            return dto
        }

        // remove tooks, and create them separately
        Set<Took> tooks = []
        tooks += dto.tooks

        tooks.each { took ->
            dto.removeFromTooks(took)
        }

        Tauthor created = dto.save()

        // readd tooks to tauthors
        tooks.each { took->
            took.tauthor = created
            took.save()
        }

        tooks.each { took->
            created.addToTooks(took)
        }
        created.save()

        return created

    }
}
```

**Example JSON**

```
{
   "class":"org.tan.Tauthor",
   "nameShort":"tankak",
   "age":13,
   "tooks":[
      {
         "class":"org.tan.Took",
         "title":"harry"
      },
      {
         "class":"org.tan.Took",
         "title":"potter"
      }
   ]
}
```